# Tokudb ROW_FORMAT is not being accepted

Tags: mysql, mariadb, tokudb

I am trying to create some tokudb tables to experiment with the different row format options to compare the compression available.

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.7/tokudb/using_tokudb.html

I have tried all the following
TOKUDB_SNAPPY
TOKUDB_ZLIB
TOKUDB_DEFAULT

With no effect.

If I just ignore it the tables are created with row_fromat = fixed.

```
MariaDB [eventlog]> show VARIABLES like "%row_format%";
+--------------------------------+-------------+
| Variable_name                  | Value       |
+--------------------------------+-------------+
| tokudb_hide_default_row_format | ON          |
| tokudb_row_format              | tokudb_zlib |
+--------------------------------+-------------+



MariaDB [eventlog]> CREATE TABLE stable1 ( column_a INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, column_b INT NOT NULL) ENGINE=TokuDB, ROW_FORMAT=TOKUDB_DEFAULT;  
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TOKUDB_DEFAULT' at line 1    
MariaDB [eventlog]> CREATE TABLE stable1 ( column_a INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, column_b INT NOT NULL) ROW_FORMAT=tokudb_default;   
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'tokudb_default' at line 1


MariaDB [eventlog]> CREATE TABLE stable1 ( column_a INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, column_b INT NOT NULL) ENGINE=TokuDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)


MariaDB [eventlog]> show table status from eventlog\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: stable1
         Engine: TokuDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Fixed
           Rows: 0
 Avg_row_length: 0
    Data_length: 0
Max_data_length: 9223372036854775807
   Index_length: 0
      Data_free: 18446744073709551615
 Auto_increment: NULL
    Create_time: 2017-02-20 12:26:18
    Update_time: 2017-02-20 12:26:18
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: latin1_swedish_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options: 
        Comment: 


 MariaDB [eventlog]> ALTER TABLE stable1 ROW_FORMAT=TOKUDB_SNAPPY;  
 ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TOKUDB_SNAPPY' at line 1


 version | 10.1.21-MariaDB  
 tokudb_version | 5.6.34-79.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using MariaDB with tokudb plugin, syntax is

`COMPRESSION=TOKUDB_LZMA` and not `ROW_FORMAT=TOKUDB_LZMA`

From [Mariadb website](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/tokudb-differences/),

The DDL syntax is different. While binaries from Tokutek have the patched SQL parser, TokuDB in MariaDB uses the special Storage Engine API extension. Thus in Tokutek binaries you write CLUSTERED KEY (columns) and, for example, ROW_FORMAT=TOKUDB_LZMA. And in MariaDB you write KEY (columns) CLUSTERING=YES and COMPRESSION=TOKUDB_LZMA.

That page also provides more info on actually checking the compression formats.

`mysql -sNe 'SELECT dictionary_name, internal_file_name FROM information_schema.tokudb_file_map WHERE table_dictionary_name = "main" OR table_dictionary_name LIKE "key-%"' |perl -F'\t' -ane '@out=qx(tokuftdump --nodata --header --rootnode /var/lib/mysql/$F[1]); foreach $ftdump (@out) { if($ftdump=~/^ compression_method=([0-9]+)$/) { print $F[0]."\t".$1."\n"; last } }'`

Different version of the above with tables names to make it easier to get check specific table names.

`mysql -sNe 'SELECT dictionary_name, internal_file_name, table_name, " " FROM information_schema.tokudb_file_map WHERE table_dictionary_name = "main" OR table_dictionary_name LIKE "key-%"'  | perl -F'\t' -ane '@out=qx(tokuftdump --nodata --header --rootnode /srv/mysql/data/$F[1]);  foreach $ftdump (@out) { if($ftdump=~/^ compression_method=([0-9]+)$/) { print $F[2]."\t".$F[0]."\t".$1."\n"; last } }' > /var/tmp/tables.compressiontype.lst`

Will produce out put like

```
head /var/tmp/tables.compressiontype.lst 
TableName   ./database/TableName-key-entity_index   11
TableName   ./database/TableName-main   11
```

The meaning of the various integers can be found in [the github repo](https://github.com/percona/PerconaFT/blob/master/buildheader/make_tdb.cc)

```
    // compression methods
printf("typedef enum toku_compression_method {\n");
printf("    TOKU_NO_COMPRESSION = 0,\n");  // "identity" compression
printf("    TOKU_SNAPPY_METHOD  = 7,\n");  // google snappy
printf("    TOKU_ZLIB_METHOD    = 8,\n");  // RFC 1950 says use 8 for zlib.  It reserves 15 to allow more bytes.
printf("    TOKU_QUICKLZ_METHOD = 9,\n");  // We use 9 for QUICKLZ (the QLZ compression level is stored int he high-order nibble).  I couldn't find any standard for any other numbers, so I just use 9. -Bradley
printf("    TOKU_LZMA_METHOD    = 10,\n");  // We use 10 for LZMA.  (Note the compression level is stored in the high-order nibble).
printf("    TOKU_ZLIB_WITHOUT_CHECKSUM_METHOD = 11,\n"); // We wrap a zlib without checksumming compression technique in our own checksummed metadata.
printf("    TOKU_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION_METHOD = 1,\n");  // default is actually quicklz
printf("    TOKU_FAST_COMPRESSION_METHOD = 2,\n");  // friendlier names
printf("    TOKU_SMALL_COMPRESSION_METHOD = 3,\n");
printf("} TOKU_COMPRESSION_METHOD;\n");
```